# Writing a method with ArrayList of strings as parameters

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I am trying to write a method that takes an ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and that places a string of four asterisks in front of every string of length 4.

However, in my code, I am getting an error in the way I constructed my method.

Here is my mark length class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Marklength {

    void marklength4(ArrayList <String> themarklength){
        for(String n : themarklength){
            if(n.length() ==4){
                themarklength.add("****");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(themarklength);
    }

}
```

And the following is my main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MarklengthTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        words.add("Kane");
        words.add("Cane");
        words.add("Fame");
        words.add("Dame");
        words.add("Lame");  
        words.add("Same");

        Marklength ish = new Marklength();

        ish.marklength4(words);

    }
}
```

Essentially in this case, it should run so it adds an arraylist with a string of `"****"` placed before every previous element of the array list because the lengths of the strings are all 4.

BTW

**This consists of adding another element**

I am not sure where I went wrong. Possibly in my for loop?

I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
    at Marklength.marklength4(Marklength.java:7)
    at MarklengthTestDrive.main(MarklengthTestDrive.java:18)
```

Thank you very much. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your error as well.

Comment: Read the javadoc of `List#add`. Then look for its overloaded method.

Comment: You are attempting to modify a temporary variable created just for that foreach loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: You may not change a List while iterating it with for ( : ). Try with for (int i = 0; i < themarklength.size(); i++) and increment i inside the loop every time you add the "****".

Comment: Do you want to append four asterisks in front of a string of length four, or do you want to add another element to the list in front of the string? So, if you have `["item"]`, do you want it took look like `["****item"]`, or `["****", "item"]`?

Comment: Add another element to the list in from of the string.

Comment: @XiJiaopin Add where in the list?  Before the matching element, after it or to the end of the list?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's think about this piece of code, and pretend like you don't get that exception:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Marklength {

    void marklength4(ArrayList <String> themarklength){
        for(String n : themarklength){
            if(n.length() ==4){
                themarklength.add("****");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(themarklength);
    }
}
```

Ok, so what happens if your list just contains `item`.

You hit the line `if(n.length() ==4){`, which is true because you are looking at item, so you go execute its block.

Next you hit the line `themarklength.add("****");`. Your list now has the element `****` at the end of it.

The loop continues, and you get the next item in the list, which happens to be the one you just added, `****`.

The next line you hit is `if(n.length() ==4){`. This is true, so you execute its block.
You go to the line `themarklength.add("****");`, and add `****` to the end of the list.

Do we see a bad pattern here? Yes, yes we do.

The Java runtime environment also knows that this is bad, which is why it **prevents** something called *Concurrent Modification*. In your case, this means you cannot modify a list while you are iterating over it, which is what that for loop does.

My best guess as to what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Marklength {

    ArrayList<String> marklength4(ArrayList <String> themarklength){
        ArrayList<String> markedStrings = new ArrayList<String>(themarklength.size());
        for(String n : themarklength){
            if(n.length() ==4){
                markedStrings.add("****");
            }
            markedStrings.add(n);
        }
        System.out.println(themarklength);
        return markedStrings;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MarklengthTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        words.add("Kane");
        words.add("Cane");
        words.add("Fame");
        words.add("Dame");
        words.add("Lame");  
        words.add("Same");

        Marklength ish = new Marklength();

        words = ish.marklength4(words);

    }
}
```

Comment: *"Java compiler also knows"* - No it doesn't `Concurrent Modification` is a runtime exception, not a compiler error, but the rest of the statement is true

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oooh, very true, my bad. I'll fix that. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, to earn that +1, what would you suggest as a fix? ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not actually sure what he wants, I just posted a comment asking him to clarify. From his question, he may want `["item"]` to become `["****item"]`, `["****","item"]`, or even `[["****"],"item"]` (which isn't possible).

Comment: This is just how I read it and it might not be right, but *""****" placed before every previous element of the array list"* would suggest `["****","item","****","item","no","****","item"]`, but that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, that's my best guess too, so I wrote a solution for it.

Comment: I'll give a +1 for that. It's a nitpick and in no detracts from your answer, but I might suggest using `ArrayList<String> markedStrings = new ArrayList<String>(themarklength.size())` as it can give better performance

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
if(n.length() ==4){
    themarklength.add("****");
}
```

Is simply trying to add `"****"` to the end of the list.  This fails because the `Iterator` used by the `for-each` loop won't allow changes to occur to the underlying `List` while it's been iterated.

<strike>You could create a copy of the `List` first...</strike>

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(themarklength);
```

Or convert it to an array of `String`

```
String[] values = themarklength.toArray(new String[themarklength.size()]);
```

And uses these as you iteration points...

```
for (String value : values) {
```

Next, you need to be able to insert a new element into the `ArrayList` at a specific point.  To do this, you will need to know the original index of the value you are working with...

```
if (value.length() == 4) {
    int index = themarklength.indexOf(value);
```

And then add a new value at the required location...

```
    themarklength.add(index, "****");
```

This will add the `"****"` at the `index` point, pushing all the other entries down

**Updated**

As has, correctly, been pointed out to me, the use of `themarklength.indexOf(value)` won't take into account the use case where the `themarklength` list contains two elements of the same value, which would return the wrong index.

I also wasn't focusing on performance as a major requirement for the providing a possible solution.

**Updated...**

As pointed out by JohnGarnder and AnthonyAccioly, you could use `for-loop` instead of a `for-each` which would allow you to dispense with the `themarklength.indexOf(value)`

This will remove the risk of duplicate values messing up the index location and improve the overall performance, as you don't need to create a second iterator...

```
// This assumes you're using the ArrayList as the copy...
for (int index = 0; index < themarklength.size(); index++) {
    String value = themarklength.get(index);
    if (value.length() == 4) {
        themarklength.add(index, "****");
        index++;
```

But which you use is up to you...

Comment: not sure where the downvote came from, yours is the same as the upvoted one (maybe post edit?)  if you use a for loop instead of the foreach style one, you don't need the extra indexof.

Comment: @JohnGardner That's true.  You have to love the courage of people who downvote questions and answers without leaving a comment...how are people suppose to learn or have the chance to improve the quality of the post :P

Comment: @JohnGardner I'm certainly not in it for the votes, as I helped the leading question to provide a possible answer ;)

Comment: yeah, I know I was just pointing out the sometimes-insanity of downvotes :)

Comment: @JohnGardner, I'm upvoting, I was the original downvoter but left for dinner. The reason for my initial downvote was that the `indexOf(value)` strategy was broken. It was wrong both in terms of performance - requiring an extra iterations every time that you find an element - and in terms correctness - if you have two equal strings if would insert `****` twice before the first position. In order to to make it work you have to track the last index and use the `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` variant, which would still  require partial new iterations.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Ahh, two `String`s good pick up, didn't think about that...I wasn't particularly seeing performance as a requirement, not saying I don't mind find betters to achieve things though ;)

Comment: Actually, the update version is still broken since the running index of `values` will not be the same as the running index of `themarklength` after the first insert. You have to keep an variable to count the number of inserts around and relocate the `index` for `add` accordingly. Demo: http://ideone.com/wdZRdb

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Updated (and tested) based on your feedback.  Cheers

Comment: @MadProgrammer, almost perfect. You just have to keep a separate variable for tracking the amount of inserted elements (check my example in the above comment). If you track both lists with `index` and use `index++` after `add`, you will skip the next element when iterating `values` (which may be a size four `string`). What I mean is, that you need to keep both `index` and a second variable to track the position delta between `themarklength` and `values`.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Sorry, though I updated it to use the `themarklength` list exclusively, doing away with a second copy of the list :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your method, you didn't modify each string in the arraylist, but only adds 4 stars to the list. So the correct way to do this is, you need to modify each element of the arraylist and replace the old string with the new one:

```
void marklength4(ArrayList<String> themarklength){
    int index = 0;
    for(String n : themarklength){
        if(n.length() ==4){
            n = "****" + n;
        }
        themarklength.set(index++, n);
    }
    System.out.println(themarklength);
}
```

If this is not what you want but you want to add a new string "****" before each element in the arraylist, then you can use `listIterator` method in the `ArrayList` to add new additional element before EACH string if the length is 4.

```
    ListIterator<String> it = themarklength.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        String name = it.next();
        if(name.length() == 4) {
            it.previous();
            it.add("****");
            it.next();
        }
    }
```

The difference is: ListIterator allows you to modify the list when iterating through it and also allows you to go backward in the list.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought the OP wanted to do as well, but I believe they want to add `"****"` BEFORE each matching element, not prefix it - could be wrong, but that's how I now read it :P

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) instead of a for each,  [`listiterator.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-) likely do exactly what you want.

```
public void marklength4(List<String> themarklength){
    final ListIterator<String> lit = 
        themarklength.listIterator(themarklength.size());
    boolean shouldInsert = false;   
    while(lit.hasPrevious()) {
        if (shouldInsert) {
            lit.add("****");
            lit.previous();
            shouldInsert = false;
        }
        final String n = lit.previous();
        shouldInsert = (n.length() == 4);
    }
    if (shouldInsert) {
        lit.add("****");
    }
}
```

---

[**Working example**](http://ideone.com/PGOlKz)

Comment: I thought this might break, and while I like the idea, it will add values "after" the last element, requiring to start messing about with `previous`, `next`...:P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, acutally, before just means iterate in reverse. Check my example.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I remember this lovely error from the good old days. The problem is that your `ArrayList` isn't completely populated by the time the array element is to be accessed. Think of it, you create the object and then immediately start looping it. The object hence, has to populate itself with the values as the loop is going to be running.

The simple way to solve this is to pre-populate your ArrayList.

```
public class MarklengthTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList<String>() {{ 

        words.add("Kane");
        words.add("Cane");
        words.add("Fame");
        words.add("Dame");
        words.add("Lame");  
        words.add("Same");
        }};
    }
}
```

Do tell me if that fixes it. You can also use a `static` initializer.

Comment: So I got 
"Cannot refer to a non-final variable words inside an inner class defined in a different method."

Answer (score 0):

make temporary arraylist, modify this list and copy its content at the end to the original list

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MarkLength {
    void marklength4(ArrayList <String> themarklength){
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String n : themarklength){
            if(n.length() ==4){
                temp.add(n);
                temp.add("****");
            }
        }
        themarklength.clear();
        themarklength.addAll(temp);
        System.out.println(themarklength);
    }
}
```